# How hard to migrate from IaaS to PaaS on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, paas, iaas

So I'm thinking of dipping a toe in the Azure pool

Our web App Suite will soon be a pure ASP.Net + SQL Server affair

For various reasons it will be simpler to initially create a SQL VM and run everything from there initially.

**How hard will it be to ...**

- **...migrate SQL off the VM and into either "Cloud Services" or "Data Management"?**
- **...migrate the suite of WebApps off the VM and into "Websites"?**

It is my understanding that having achieved this migration, the OS level updates will no longer be my concern as they will be handled by the service. Thus at this point I'll be able to throw the original VM away :)

Comment: We have migrated ~95% of our enterprise suite of SaaS products to Azure's PaaS offerings. It was a LOT of work but I'm very glad we did it! My ultimate (at this point) impressions are this: 1) ROI for getting apps into Web Roles pays off **VERY** quickly! 2) SQL Azure's limitations are quite annoying (especially the lack of *good* backup solutions). 3) If you're not willing to invest in automated deployments from the beginning, don't bother. You MUST have that!

Comment: what are automated deployments? and how do they pertain to Azure?

Comment: @Rob: Look into Continuous Integration and Build Servers. TFS can do this and Jenkins is another popular one. Ultimately, there are many, MANY different options here and this is a HUGE conversation that won't fit here. Go Google around and that should help you a LOT!

Answer (score 5):

This isn't exactly answering your questions, but it might help educate you on more questions to ask and giving you a boost out of the gate. These were all lessons learned before, during, or after our migration of our systems to Azure. Now that we're up there, we have a ~50GB database with ~6 services running across ~30 instances. As long as our database backup behaves, total amount of effort in upgrading *all* of this is less than an hour (and could be much less if we didn't have many safeguards meant to force us to be aware of what's going on during the migration process - we don't want it to be *too* easy to deploy just to protect us from ourselves).

**Preparing to migrate your system to Azure:**

If you're planning to go to Azure, you first need to make sure your architectures and technologies are compatible. This isn't to say you have to code everything specific to Azure. This means some of the following things:

- **You should realize that "high availability" does *not* mean "error-free".** In fact, high-availability environments usually have *more* errors that you have to handle and manage. For example, if you have a request going over the network to a server that just had a motherboard fry and was taken offline, that network request will be unsuccessful. That's not typically a problem you code for in "standard" server apps. To take it even further, what if that failed network is for a Database Connection that gets put back into a connection pool? That will cause that connection to be poisoned and broken the next time somebody pulls it out regardless of the future state of that server that went poof! There are just some extra things to worry about here because you're no longer depending on just 1 network with 4 servers on it but are now depending on hundreds of networks with thousands of servers on them. That 0.05% error scenario will happen MUCH more often to you than you've ever experienced in the past and you really have to be aware of this!
- **You should use dependency-injection** to easily change things around. Proper separation of concerns will changes that seem very difficult become very easy in Azure.
- **You should use architectures for "high-availability"**. For example, a web application that would break when ran in a web farm would also break in Azure but a web application designed to work in a web farm would be very easy to run in Azure.
- **You should have automated deployments and configuration transforms** for all of your applications. Anything else is just unsustainable unless it's nothing more than one little web site or something like that.
- Depending on your needs, **you can do it in phases**. If database latency is something that isn't a big deal, perhaps a hybrid approach (over VPN from Azure to your data center) is acceptable to get your apps in Azure first while you later migrate your database. Or perhaps the opposite. What we did was keep primary apps and database in our data center but put secondary apps up in Azure first. Then some primary apps (that took a performance hit for a month until) later our database and critical apps. That final migration sure made for a very long weekend and not much sleep, but it is SOO much nicer now that we're done!

**Migrating your applications to Azure:**

This ultimately depends very heavily on what your application is or does, and every scenario has different steps/issues/benefits. I'm not going to cover this deeply other than to say, "Use Google, it's your friend!". Beyond that, for us, getting our applications up into Azure was the largest payoff when compared to our data. The ROI on our app migration was less than a month between hosting costs, licensing, and management effort. Instead of taking a couple days to setup a server, I can now take a day to setup an entirely new and duplicated environment of all of our SaaS applications/databases/etc and have them running on ~25 different Cloud instances!

Instead of trying to tell you how to migrate these, let me give you a few words of caution so you know sooner rather than later:

- If you have app problems in Windows 2012, humor me and try it in Windows 2008 R2. There are a couple bugs in some of the 2012 images that they've prepared. It's incredibly trivial to switch back and forth!
- Go make your logging 1000x's better than what it is now. If you don't do that now, you'll regret it.
- Don't depend 100% on the easy-to-implement "Azure Logging". It works well enough but it more-or-less requires your applications to start successfully and is absolutely useless in debugging startup problems. If you don't have an alternative, then you will waste many, many hours just debugging stupid little problems when your app starts up. By the time you're done with it, you could have easily added 5 other logging frameworks and had an amazingly awesome logging system in place plus a running app instead of nothing but a running app to show for the same amount of time. Really, do this! (Profiling is a good idea as well, although Mini-Profiler has load-balancing issues if you have multiple instances.)
- If you add new endpoints to your deployment (ports, etc), you **cannot** simply "Upgrade" an existing deployment. You must delete it (the deployment, not the service) and install from scratch. You can delete the Staging one, deploy to Staging, then swap.
- If you have WCF apps, pretend you don't know about Windows Activation Services. They're disabled in Azure by default. You can either hack them to turn them on (startup scripts) or create your own self-hosting application. We self-host so we can more easily tweak service configurations once we're deployed (it's not easy to edit web.config files in a way that sticks in Azure). Web services work in "IIS" in Azure but TCP, named pipes, etc. do not.
- Go learn about and add the Transient Errors Application Block (or something equivalent) to anything you communicate with. If you don't do it now, you'll regret it.
- Go make your logging better! Really, really, REALLY do this!

**Migrating your SQL Server Database to Azure:**

Getting your database up into Azure is a bit of a painful process. There isn't a quick and easy way to just get it up there and making it work. Some people have to make some major changes while others just have to tweak a few ignorable things here and there. However, no matter how large or small your database is, you really REALLY must devote a lot of time to testing it. Test your migration process. Test your scripts to prepare your database. Test the performance and stability of the database up in the cloud. Test your backup procedures. Test your upgrade procedures. Test your backup restoration procedures. Test ALL of this because I guarantee you that you will find some surprises!

Schema:

- **Go learn about all of the limitations of SQL Azure**. No Heaps, etc. Learn them before you start! Go learn them now! They're all mostly to very reasonable.
- **Be aware of the 2GB T-Log limitation**! This means some very large indexes can never be rebuilt! (that said, our 30GB table isn't yet hitting this)
- To deploy your schema, go into SSMS for your local db and use the "Tasks -> Extract Data-tier Application..." feature (it's in different areas of the menu in different versions of SSMS). Take this file and go into SSMS for your Azure database and use the "Deploy Data-tier Application" feature. (This will help you catch *some* of the Azure limitations you aren't honoring if this process fails.) This is, by far, the easiest way to get an empty version of your database up into Azure.
- Use a tool like Redgate SQL Compare to verify your work (you'll have to tweak a couple options, like `WITH NOCHECK` to get a clean comparison).
- You'll have to cleanup users, schemas, broken sprocs, etc. before you succeed at this. (this is a good thing!)

Data:

- **Go learn about all of the limitations of SQL Azure**. Learn them before you start! Go learn them now! They're all mostly to very reasonable.
- Go download the Azure Database Migration Wizard from Codeplex (or wherever the latest version is). It's not the most amazing software (kinda unstable) but even if it crashes once or twice on you, it'll still save you a LOT of time!
- I **strongly** recommend RedGate's SQL Data Compare. The previously-mentioned migration wizard will help you identify problems (it's on you to fix those) and will get you ~98% migrated but you'll want to come back and clean up after it. It has some bugs that misses nullable BIT fields (and upper ascii characters) and some other things that a tool like SQL Data Compare can easily identify and fix. It can also give you the peace-of-mind that you can depend on your database.
- If your database is large, consider spinning up a temporary VM in Azure (they have them with SQL Server pre-installed and available in ~20 minutes) to do your migrations from. If you do this, it's best to upload a compressed database backup to Blob storage (Cerebrata's storage too is great for this) and then grab it and restore to SQL Server in that VM. Then stage your migrations all from there!

Test, test, TEST!!!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful running SQL on a VM, it's not a high availability solution. Azure VMs are prone to restarting from time to time. Unless you have multiple VMs running SQL Server in an availability group, or you have some sort of mirroring and load balancing setup, you won't have a high availability solution. I too originally favoured the IaaS to PaaS route, in the end it seemed to be a false economy as migrating IaaS to PaaS is about as much work as migrating on-premise to PaaS. In the end I decided to take the time to optimise my application for PaaS, i.e. moving durable storage to blobs, implementing transient error handling and retry logic,  etc.

What you're proposing is certainly possible but having a multi VM arrangement to deliver high availability SQL takes a bit of work and is expensive! Have a read of the following guide, it was really helpful to me when I started the migration process:

[Top 7 Concerns of Migrating a .NET Application to Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peterlau/archive/2012/04/25/top-7-concerns-of-migrating-an-asp-net-application-to-windows-azure.aspx)

Comment: What this guy said. "Reliable" Azure VMs takes a lot of work! I think the most official solution is taking 2-3 VMs and ultimately clustering them together. For 98% of people, this is most certainly NOT what you want to do. That said, moving your SQL database into SQL Azure is also a very big leap of faith. There is a LOT of "gotchas" involved in this. While that is likely your end goal, if you jump to it quickly, please, test test test! And study up on the limitations. As is, DBAs tend to hate SQL Azure because there are so many maintenance things you simply cannot do.

Comment: It is indeed a leap of faith! and I second the need to test! I'm still working through optimising all our queries now (after 3 months) and trying to develop a toolset for maintaining our DB once in Azure. Even running backups is a minefield compared to what you can do in SQL Server. But yes, fiendishly test and remove as much doubt as possible. On the plus side you will hopefully end up with a highly scalable solution, so don't be put off! Developing on performance hardware can lead to sloppy code, the cloud makes you very aware of this.

Comment: Another +1 on the backup situation comment! I'll be much more blunt and flat-out say that Azure's built-in backup solutions are **awful** right now. For example, the **only possible** way to get a transactionally-consistent backup is a process that takes almost 10 minutes per GB. That means 8 hrs for a 50GB database and 24 hours for a 150GB database. Our DB is 50GB and an 8-hour backup process isn't an option so we use the option that isn't transactionally-consistent but fortunately, that's sufficient for us. We also use Red Gate's solution to automate it. It usually takes ~1.5 hours.

Comment: By the way, don't take this as "doom and gloom" talk. Take this as "we're trying to make you aware of the large concerns so they don't catch you off-guard". Despite these major annoyances, I'm still very happy we have our database up in SQL Azure now and I am in no way envious of having it in-house or even in Azure VMs! There's certainly a lot of growth for them to do but they currently have a very good system right now as well!

Answer (score 1):

Just yesterday Microsoft announced their plan to host also Iaas solutions and not only Saas solution on their Azure platform.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/04/16/windows-azure-general-availability-of-infrastructure-as-a-service-iaas.aspx

About migration, it really depends. We work with a distribution mechanism: TFS + Octopus so the deployment is very easy and it works on Iaas or SQL Azure, it doesn't really matter.
There are also other things to keep into consideration when moving into Saas. Probably your code should be refactored if it's not Saas oriented or your application may have a very high hosting cost over Azure.

Comment: Clarification: The plan (and preview) of IaaS was announced June 2012. Yesterday's announcement was about the service going live into Production, meaning Service Level Agreements are in effect, as well as official pricing, new VM sizes, and also the production release of Virtual Networks (also in preview since June 2012).